# How to fix "no matching function to call to..." in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, binary

Hey I want to load the binary data of my wav file in my array but I get an error like: "not matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream(Array&, size_t&)'" and I want to do it with templates, does anyone know how to fix this?

```
int main(){


    ifstream infile("soundeffect.wav", std::ios::binary);

    infile.seekg(0, infile.end);
    size_t length = infile.tellg();
    infile.seekg(44, infile.beg);

    Array<int> array(length);


    infile.read(array, length); //error in this line

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is `Array`? Its not a standard class.

Comment: Look up what [`read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read)'s first parameter is and convert your object to that type.

Comment: Please post proper [mcve]. What's `Array<int>`? There's no `std::basic_ifstream(Array&, size_t&)` function, so the error is correct.

Comment: did you put before the main: using namepace std;

Comment: You forgot the part of the error message where the compiler tells you what calls _would_ be valid and explains why yours doesn't match any of them. Find the you were going for and look at what the compiler says about it.

Comment: Array is a class I wrote and yes I put 'using namepace std;'

Comment: You need to define how to read your _Array_, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get an error like: "not matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream(Array&, size_t&)'"
>
> Array is a class I wrote and yes I put 'using namepace std;'

If I well understand you have something like :

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

template<typename K>
class Array {
  public:
    Array(size_t ln) { /*...*/ }
  // ...
};

int main(){
  ifstream infile("soundeffect.wav", std::ios::binary);

  infile.seekg(0, infile.end);
  size_t length = infile.tellg();
  infile.seekg(44, infile.beg);

  Array<int> array(length);

  infile.read(array, length); //error in this line

  return 0;
}
```

with that when I compile I also have

> c.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
>   c.cc:21:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream::read(Array&, size_t&)’
>      infile.read(array, length); //error in this line

and this is normal because there is no reason *ifstream::read* knows how to read an *Array*

One way is to define the operation *read* on *Array* like for instance

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

template<typename K>
class Array {
  public:
    Array(size_t ln) : len(ln) { /* ... */ }
    istream & read(istream & in, size_t & len);
    // ...
  private:
    size_t len;
  // ...
};      

// ln is an input-output var allowing to know how much elements
// was read, returns the istream to know if an error occurs
// and which one
template<typename K>
istream & Array<K>::read(istream & in, size_t & ln) {
  size_t n = min(ln, len);

  for (ln = 0; ln != n; ++ln)
    if (! in.read(??, ??))
      break;

  return in;
}

int main(){
  ifstream infile("soundeffect.wav", std::ios::binary);

  infile.seekg(0, infile.end);
  size_t length = infile.tellg();
  infile.seekg(44, infile.beg);

  Array<int> array(length);

  array.read(infile, length);

  return 0;
}
```

However are you sure you can define a generic class *Array* allowing to read a *wav* file into an `Array<int>` ?

Comment: thank you that was really helpful! I guess I've to change it to Array<char>

Comment: @newlearner you welcome, yes a char is probably more appropriated, but are you sure you need to define your class Array for that ?

Comment: It's a requirement to write my own class so I guess yes :)